# Numpy matrix multiplication issue with 20 elements

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, precision, multiplication

I am using a matrix multiplication method to retrieve the position of True and False into an array; this is necessary because I cannot use a for look (I have thousands of records).
The procedure is the following:

```
import numpy as np
# Create a test array
test_array = np.array([[False, True, False, False, False, True]])
# Create a set of unique "tens", each one identifying a position
uniq_tens = [10 ** (i) for i in range(0, test_array.shape[1])]
# Multiply the matrix
print(int(np.dot(test_array, uniq_tens)[0]))
100010
```

The 10010 must be read from right to left (0=False, 1=True, 0=False, 0=False, 1=True). Everything works fine except if the test_array is of **20 elements**.

```
# This works fine - Test with 21 elements
test_array = np.array([[False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True]])
print(test_array.shape[1])
uniq_tens = [10 ** (i) for i in range(0, test_array.shape[1])]
print(int(np.dot(test_array, uniq_tens)[0]))
21
111000000000000000010

# This works fine - Test with 19 elements
test_array = np.array([[False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True]])
print(test_array.shape[1])
uniq_tens = [10 ** (i) for i in range(0, test_array.shape[1])]
print(int(np.dot(test_array, uniq_tens)[0]))
19
1000000000000000010

# This does not work - Test with 20 elements
test_array = np.array([[False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True]])
print(test_array.shape[1])
uniq_tens = [10 ** (i) for i in range(0, test_array.shape[1])]
print(int(np.dot(test_array, uniq_tens)[0]))
20
10000000000000000000
```

I tested with numpy version 1.16.4/1.19.4 and 1.19.5. Could you please help me in understanding why? I am worried it can happen also with other numbers, not only 20.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Alternatively, use `np.where` to retrieve the indices of the True values.

Comment: Your numbers probably become too large, and you are hit by numerical imprecision. The result of the `np.dot` operation is a float64, which has limited accuracy; roughly between 15 and 17 significant digits. Which is less than 20.

Comment: Why it works for 19 and 21? I am guessing just chance. You might find an underlying reason why this happens to work, but overall, your algorithm quickly stops being accurate, and should not be used.

Comment: Something is strange in `np.dot(test_array, uniq_tens)`.  For 19, the dtype is int64, for 20 -> float64, for 21 -> object.

Comment: The int64 and float64 can be explained; the object type is surprising, but also showing in a way that this is beyond the precision that numpy can afford.

Comment: @9769953 yeah the object array is the strange part.

Comment: @DanielF Fun fact: I obtain a Python int for the 21-element variant, as a result of `np.dot`. Probably the underlying (BLAS? LAPACK?) routine, but it's surprising it also returns the correct answer for this case.

Comment: "I cannot use a for look". I take it you mean "for loop". But you also mean a for loop in Python. Because under the hood, matrix multiplication is a (complicated) for loop anyway, just in C or Fortran. So: use `np.where` and things are ten times easier and clearer.

Comment: I don't understand how this calculation is supposed to help "find" the True values. Don't you still have to iterate over the decimal digits of the number (which in turn either requires doing arithmetic or converting to string) in order to see which are `1`? Also, "thousands" of records is normally a trivial problem size. Are you sure there isn't an algorithmic complexity problem at a higher level / somewhere else in the code?

Comment: It is not clear why you do need to do this computation. `np.nonzero(test_array)` will give you the positions of the `True` values in `test_array`. If you need to construct an `int` out of `test_array` it should be fast enough / faster to use Python arithmetics directly `sum(10 ** i for i, x in enumerate(test_array.tolist()) if x)` (at least most of the times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation

You are hitting int64 limit:

```py
print(len(str(2 ** (64 - 1))))
# 19
```

when computing `uniq_tens`, which causes some data type problems in conjuction with `np.dot()` with mixed data type inputs.

---

More precisely, what happens here is that:

1. `uniq_tens` content is Python's `int`, which is arbitrary precision
2. when you call `np.dot()` the `uniq_tens` list is converted to a NumPy array, with unspecified data type

   - when the maximum value is up until `np.iinfo(np.int64).max` the datatype is inferred to be `int64`
   - when the maximum value is up between `np.iinfo(np.int64).max` and `np.iinfo(np.uint64).max` the datatype is inferred to be `uint64`
   - when the maximum value is above that it retains the Python object and falls back to arbitrary precision
3. There might be an extra cast in `np.dot()` if the inputs are of mixed dtype. In the case of `np.bool_` and `np.uint64` the inferred common type is `np.float64`.

Now:

```py
max_int64 = np.iinfo(np.int64).max
print(max_int64, len(str(max_int64)))
# 9223372036854775807 19

max_uint64 = np.iinfo(np.uint64).max
print(max_uint64, len(str(max_uint64)))
# 18446744073709551615 20

print(repr(np.array([max_int64])))
# array([9223372036854775807])
print(repr(np.array([max_uint64])))
# array([18446744073709551615], dtype=uint64)
print(repr(np.array([max_uint64 + 1])))
# array([18446744073709551616], dtype=object)
```

So, up until 19 and above 21 everything works well.
When you use 20, it does convert to `uint64`.
However, when you use `np.dot()` it realizes it can no longer use `int64` nor `uint64` to hold the result and casts everything to `np.float64`:

```py
print(np.dot([1], [max_int64]))
# 9223372036854775807
print(np.dot([1], [max_uint64]))
# 1.8446744073709552e+19
print(np.dot([1], [max_uint64 + 1]))
# 18446744073709551616
```

Instead, when you start with something that is already a uint64 it keeps using that:

```py
print(np.dot(np.array([1], dtype=np.uint64), [max_uint64]))
# 18446744073709551616
print(np.dot(np.array([4321], dtype=np.uint64), [max_uint64]))
# 18446744073709547295  # wrong result
```

which has its own overflow problems.

---

## Mitigation

One way to make sure the above code works all the time is to force the `dtype` of `uniq_tens` to `object`:

```py
import numpy as np


test_array = np.array([[0, 1] + [0] * 17 + [1]])
uniq_tens = np.array([(10 ** i) for i in range(test_array.shape[1])], dtype=object)

print(test_array.shape[1], int(np.dot(test_array, uniq_tens)[0]))
# 20 10000000000000000010
```

---

## Other approaches

If we are after the fastest way of computing the integer with a specific base, a number of approaches can be devised:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


def bools_to_int(arr, base=2):
    return sum(base ** i for i, x in enumerate(arr.tolist()) if x)


def bools_to_int_dot(arr, base=2):
    pows = np.array([base ** i for i in range(len(arr))], dtype=object)
    return np.dot(arr, pows)


def bools_to_int_mul_sum(arr, base=2):
    pows = np.array([base ** i for i in range(len(arr))], dtype=object)
    return np.sum(arr * pows)


@nb.njit
def bools_to_int_nb(arr, base=2):
    n = arr.size
    result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if arr[i]:
            result += base ** i
    return result
```

The looped approach can be accelerated also with Cython:

```
%%cython -c-O3 -c-march=native -a
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, cdivision=True, infer_types=True

# cimport numpy as cnp
# cimport cython as ccy

# import numpy as np
# import cython as cy


cpdef bools_to_int_cy(arr, base=2):
    cdef long n = arr.size
    result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if arr[i]:
            result += base ** i
    return result
```

Note that the `bools_to_int_nb()` approach will work until the int64 limit.

Since the power operation is one of the most expensive in such computation, it can be precomputed to further speed-up multiple calls:

```py
MAX_PRE_VAL = 256
BASES = list(range(2, 16))
POWS = {
    b: np.array([b ** i for i in range(MAX_PRE_VAL)])
    for b in BASES}


def bools_to_int_pre(arr, base=2, pows=POWS):
    return sum(pows[base][i] for i, x in enumerate(arr.tolist()) if x)


def bools_to_int_dot_pre(arr, base=2, pows=POWS):
    return np.dot(arr, pows[base][:len(arr)])


def bools_to_int_mul_sum_pre(arr, base=2, pows=POWS):
    return np.sum(arr * pows[base][:len(arr)])
```

It is easy to see that all methods produce the same result (save for the `bools_to_int_nb()` with the limitations already noted):

```py
funcs = (
    bools_to_int, bools_to_int_pre,
    bools_to_int_dot, bools_to_int_dot_pre,
    bools_to_int_mul_sum, bools_to_int_mul_sum_pre,
    bools_to_int_cy, bools_to_int_nb)


rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
arr = rng.integers(0, 2, 112)
for func in funcs:
    print(f"{func.__name__!s:>32}  {func(arr)}")
```

```
                    bools_to_int  3556263535586786347937292461931686
                bools_to_int_pre  3556263535586786347937292461931686
                bools_to_int_dot  3556263535586786347937292461931686
            bools_to_int_dot_pre  3556263535586786347937292461931686
            bools_to_int_mul_sum  3556263535586786347937292461931686
        bools_to_int_mul_sum_pre  3556263535586786347937292461931686
                 bools_to_int_cy  3556263535586786347937292461931686
                 bools_to_int_nb  -4825705174627124058
```

With the following code to produce the timings:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)


timings = {}
k = 16
for n in range(1, 128, 3):
    arrs = rng.integers(0, 2, (k, n))
    print(f"n = {n}")
    timings[n] = []
    base = [funcs[0](arr) for arr in arrs]
    for func in funcs:
        res = [func(arr) for arr in arrs]
        is_good = base == res
        timed = %timeit -r 8 -n 16 -q -o [func(arr) for arr in arrs]
        timing = timed.best * 1e6 / k
        timings[n].append(timing if is_good else None)
        print(f"{func.__name__:>24}  {is_good}  {timing:10.3f} µs")
```

to be plotted with:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data=timings, index=[func.__name__ for func in funcs]).transpose()
df.plot(marker='o', xlabel='Input size / #', ylabel='Best timing / µs', figsize=(10, 8))
```

[image: benchmark]

Showing that before hitting the `int64` limit, the `bools_to_int_nb()` approach is the fastest by far and large.
Conversely, for larger values `np.dot()` with pre-computing is the fastest.
Without pre-computing, resorting to simple manual looping is the fastest, and the Cython acceleration provides a small but appreciable speed-up.

Beware that power-of-2 problem can probably be optimized more.

Comment: That is working and thanks a lot for the explanation! Just one curiosity: do you think that if I use base 2 instead of base 10 it will work anyway?
`uniq_twos = np.array([(2** i) for i in range(test_array.shape[1])], dtype=object)`

At the end of the day I am interested in having a unique number for each row of test array where the position of the True's is the same.

Comment: Perhaps we should all take a moment to appreciate the fact that if you force `dtype` to `object` you can effectively vectorize bigint arithmetics.

Comment: @GiuseppeSalerno It will surely work. If you use base 2 arithmetic the problem will pop up much later (above 63 instead of 19).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and indeed it looks like the error is caused by a floating point precision obtained after the `np.dot` function. You might convert it back to int, but since you have a float as an intermediate step, a conversion goes poorly. Also, the fact that it works for lengths 18 and 19 is a pure coincidence - I have tested it for other test_arrays and got errors there.

In fact, I believe this is rather fortunate, because your solution wont work for larger numbers. Below you can find a one-liner which solves your problem and should work for arbitrarily large arrays:

```
int(''.join(reversed(test_array.as_type(int).astype(str).flatten())))
```

What happens to the test_array here:

- convert to `int` to get zeroes and ones
- convert to `str` since we will want to concatenate
- flatten the array to make it 1D (or use a 1D input instead)
- reverse the contents using `reversed`
- concatenate all the individual `'0'` and `'1'` strings
- convert the output back to `int`

Answer (score 0):

For your use-case, I think best method would be:

```
int( 
    np.binary_repr( 
                   (2 ** np.where(test_array)[1]).sum()
                  ) 
   )
```

(multi-line for clarity, since there's a lot of nested parentheses there)

`np.binary_repr()` returns a string that can be then cast to `int` directly, skipping over many of the casting problems.